# Type casting/ conversion dilemma

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

I'm still only starting out in C++ and haven't dealt with much type casting yet. I was under the impression that the syntax is `(type) (variables)` however, this does not seem to work in this case.

```
float calcSphere (int radius)
{
    float sphereSA;

    sphereSA =  (4 * PI *  (radius*radius));

    return sphereSA;

}
```

PI is a symbolic constant declared using `#define PI 3.14` at the top of the code, I attempted to fix this problem by using `(float) (4 * PI *  (radius*radius))` but this did not solve anything. Google seems to return pretty obscure results on the subject too. Any solutions?

Comment: It works for me, what error are you getting?

Comment: Surface area of sphere. Error I'm getting is invalid type argument of unary (have "int").

Comment: @Revoo Sorry. I didn't pay close attention to function name. I was just looking at the variable `radius`. The formula is correct. I amn't sure what exactly is your problem. Please post the complete program and the error message.

Comment: @Revoo Of unary *what*? Are you posting the *entire* relevant code?

Comment: unary "*" my apologies. The block of code in the OP is where the error occurs. It is fixed when you replace "PI" with 3, so I presume it was a casting error, "3.14 * int"

Comment: @Revoo "unary *" implies you have an extra `*` in there and so one is being treated as the pointer dereference operator. Can you post the line where you `#define PI`? Are you sure it's `#define PI 3.14`?

Comment: @Revoo It should work as is unless something wrong with your #define. Demo: http://ideone.com/61zokQ

Comment: @Pubby I double checked, and lo and behold I had a semi colon at the end of the constant declaration which I could of sworn I did not put. I feel like an idiot now, but at least I learned what unary is. Code is working as intended now, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Revoo You can post that as an answer to your own question. Anyways, `#define` shouldn't be used in C++ to define constants as you can use the type safe `const` or `constexpr` keyword instead. Also, C-style casts shouldn't be used since the safer `static_cast` keyword can be used. You wouldn't have had these problems if you used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but, are you getting a warning about initialization casting a double to a float (using MSVS)?  Or possibly it's messing up b/c everything is ending up being cast as an integer b/c of the '4'?

If so, the problem is that when you type out a number it's a double.  But you're using it as a float, to resolve it, that number needs to be what is cast.  E.g.

```
sphereSA = ((float) 4 * (float) PI * radius * radius);
```

But, it would be better to give the compiler some type information about PI.  E.g.

```
namespace MyConstants {
    const float PI = 3.141;
}
sphereSA = ((float) 4 * MyConstants::PI * radius * radius);
```

Answer (score -4):

You're using the C style cast. The syntax for casts has changed with C++.
You want to look for something like this:

```
dynamic_cast<something*>( yourthing );
```